# In the "Welcome to [...], check out the FAQ!" header, middle click doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

I visited a SE site I'm not registered on, and got the "Welcome" header. I middleclicked "FAQ" in the Welcome header to open the FAQ in a new tab, but nothing happened. The context menu (when rightclicking the FAQ link) doesn't contain "Open link" either. Basically, it doesn't seem to be a real link, but a half-working JS imitation of a link.

Browsers tested: Chrome 7.0.517.44, Firefox 3.6.10

Comment: Your mouse has a left, middle and right click buttons?

Comment: @Andrew On some mice, the mousewheel can be depressed and acts as a center click button.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, appears to be some JS without a real link target.

```
<span class="notify-text">
Welcome to Q&amp;A for electronics and robotics hardware hacking enthusiasts. -- check out the 
<a onclick="notify.closeFirstTime()">FAQ</a>!
</span>
```